# Why I have no breeze auth block in Laravel/Livewire app?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-10, laravel-breeze

I need to add breeze to my new Laravel Livewire app and reading manuals

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze-installation

I installed breeze with command :

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev
```

and selected option

```
● Livewire (Volt Functional API) with Alpine
```

not shure actually is it a valid option ?

Also I selected
No dark mode support

and

PHPUnit

and running

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

with success

reopening home page I did not find auth block(links to Register/Login pages) in top right corner of the page

I manually upgrated all packages in composer.json :

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
"keywords": [
"laravel",
"framework"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
"php": "^8.1",
"cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^10.0",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.8.1",
"laravel/framework": "^10.43.0",
"laravel/sanctum": "^3.3.3",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.9",
"livewire/livewire": "^3.0",
"livewire/volt": "^1.0",
"spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^11.2.0",
"spatie/laravel-permission": "^6.3",
"te7a-houdini/laravel-trix": "^2.0.9"
},
"require-dev": {
"fakerphp/faker": "^1.23.1",
"laravel/breeze": "^1.28.1",
"laravel/pint": "^1.13.10",
"laravel/sail": "^1.27.3",
"mockery/mockery": "^1.6.7",
"nunomaduro/collision": "^7.10.0",
"phpunit/phpunit": "^10.5.10",
"spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.4.2"
},
"autoload": {
"files": [
"app/Library/helper.php"
],
"psr-4": {
"App\\": "app/",
"Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
"Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
}
},
"autoload-dev": {
"psr-4": {
"Tests\\": "tests/"
}
},
"scripts": {
"post-autoload-dump": [
"Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
"@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
],
"post-update-cmd": [
"@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
],
"post-root-package-install": [
"@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
],
"post-create-project-cmd": [
"@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
]
},
"extra": {
"laravel": {
"dont-discover": []
}
},
"config": {
"optimize-autoloader": true,
"preferred-install": "dist",
"sort-packages": true,
"allow-plugins": {
"pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
"php-http/discovery": true
}
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true
}
```

and runned composer - but still auth block ?

What did I miss?

Comment: What do you mean authblock? Do you mean when you login to your app?

Comment: Laravel breeze is for new application (fresh install). Technically, you could install even if the project is not fresh but chances are there are conflicting files since breeze will create/update files. Now as for the auth block. If you meant the div block on top right where you can see a dropdown if your name, profile and logout buttons, you would need to login to your app first( granted you already have an account created) or register a new one.

Comment: auth block - links to Register/Login pages

Comment: Do you mean I need : 1) Install new  Laravel app 2) Install breeze 3) Install  Livewire? If yes please link to manuall

Comment: Yes. here is livewire docs after breeze: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart#install-livewire

Comment: links to Register/Login pages -> same after installing breeze. btw, you might have executed `npm run build` by accident, Check public/dist or public/build, if found, delete them